# Ubuntu Operates Poorly On Dual Boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, hard-drive

I've set up two Windows 10/Ubuntu 16.04 dual boots on older laptops and loved the experience.

On my new laptop I had Ubuntu 16.04 pre-installed on one of three internal hard drives (the other two blank). My intention is to have Ubuntu 17.04 installed on one of the hard drives (a Samsung SSD 960 EVO 1TB), and Windows 10 installed on one of the other hard drives (another Samsung " " " "). My planned process: Install Windows on hard drive 2, uninstall Ubuntu on hard drive 1, reinstall Ubuntu on hard drive 1. Simple.

Installing on two separate hard drives actually proved more of a challenge than my previous experience with partitioned single hard drives, but I eventually got things working (presumably I did something during this frustrated process which is responsible for my current issues). I currently have my desired set up, BUT-- Ubuntu is operating very poorly.

For example:
Windows boots *in 15 seconds & works like a charm*, while Ubuntu clocks in at *about 2 minutes and 20 seconds*; a couple of times Ubuntu has frozen while booting; after booting, Ubuntu is noticeably sluggish and clunky-- although nothing seems out of place when I run `htop` or `iotop`; Ubuntu has frozen in hibernation; a couple of my custom desktop behavior settings- but not all- were sporadically reset to default during unrelated reboots; one of the apps I have used frequently on past computers, Caffeine, simply won't open, and I couldn't find other users who've experienced the same problem; 'System program problems' have been randomly detected a number of times, but the only two which would open a details window were for 'usr/lib/xorg/Xorg' 'ProblemType crash', and 'usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/unity-greeter-session-broadcast/unity...' 'ProblemType crash'. It's a generally crappy experience.

I've read that there are bugs with Ubuntu 17.04 on Samsung drives, but I haven't experienced any of the problems I read on forums regarding that.

I tried to fix any corruption:

`sudo fsck -y /dev/nvme0n1p1
[sudo] password for jlinux:
fsck from util-linux 2.29
fsck.fat 4.0 (2016-05-06)
0x41: Dirty bit is set. Fs was not properly unmounted and some data may be corrupt.
Automatically removing dirty bit.
Performing changes.
/dev/nvme0n1p1: 213 files, 11207/130812 clusters`

This resulted in no noticeable changes.

I read that similar issues can occur when one's Ubuntu installation lacks a swap drive, but mine does indeed have a swap drive.

I ran `dmesg` to check for errors (but admittedly don't have the best knowledge base to know when I'm seeing a problem in that long list), only two things really stood out:

`mmc0: Unknown controller version (3). You may experience problems.` (this was the only text written in red.)

and

`ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20160930/nsarguments-95)` (this was written over and over a handful of times)

But after some research it appears neither of these are issues of substance. I have the full printout of `dmesg` if needed.

I decided to try totally re-installing Ubuntu and telling my new installation to wipe the drive.

To my dismay the live environment froze during the installation set-up.

Covering all my bases: I re-downloaded the Ubuntu 17.04 .iso, used a different USB key, and used Rufus instead of the initially used Win32 to make the key bootable.

AGAIN the system froze during the installation process [a long wait time during the 'Preparing to Install Ubuntu' options screen, followed by a complete freeze on the 'Installation Type' options screen (strangely, before it froze, the option to 'Install Now' was shadowed out when initial installation types were selected, and it froze after I tried to select the 'Something else' installation type).

I really don't want to make Windows take control of the Linux hard drive, but am feeling the walls creeping in. Please help, and if you have input please explain in step by step detail, like to a child. Thanks.

*EDIT: I had installed the proprietary drivers for a GTX 1080 as part of this process. Doing so had zero impact, save for the addition of a brief NVIDIA screen flashing during the equally long boot time.*

Comment: What kind of video card is in your new computer?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, I forgot to include that step. GTX 1080. I installed the proprietary drivers, this changed nothing except flashing an NVidia screen during the equally long boot.

Comment: Did you ever actually run the new computer with the 16.04 install? If so, how was the experience there?

Comment: I didn't actually :( I had already planned for this setup so I saw no purpose in it. I DID HOWEVER try to set-up that same 16.04 installation after I had installed Windows, because I was having some trouble getting 17.04 to install to the intended hard drive. I found I could access the original 16.04 installation from the boot menu-- which I didnt expect-- so I thought it could work. It froze during the set-up process on multiple attempts. So I went back to 17.04 and made the installation  work. Thanks for your interest.